# FastAPI refuse to connect request from Kong Gateway

Tags: fastapi, api-gateway, kong

I want to access to my FastAPI application for image prediction. After configuring the Kong gatway,  I am able to see the services / routes but cannot access to the service by Insomnia.
Please check the screen shots.

KONG LOGS :
[KONG LOGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPMC9.png)
Insomnia output : bad gateway
[INSOMNIA OUTPUT - BAD GATEWAY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQH4r.png)
FastAPI dashbord:
[FastAPI dashbord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxZrh.png)
Fast API application running:
[my app running and no receive requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7K02.png)

I tried to check if the API is accessible by link directly by browsing http://127.0.0.1:8080/predict/image but no response. But the CURL command works curl -X 'POST' 
'http://127.0.0.1:8080/predict/image' but giving resposne as bad request.

Comment: Actually the service is running and accepts get/post request when using direct service end point (127.0.0.1.8080) but not when trying to get response from gateway (127.0.0.1:8000/service_name)

Comment: How are you running these services? As containers In docker? As pure services on the server? Please include relevant details _in your question_ and not as images; images are bad for accessibility, can't be searched for and can't be copy and pasted.

Comment: The services are running on my host and not as containers. Do you think that it might be port access? for example does my container (Kong) has access to host's 8080 port?